# How to filter static resources requests from web access logs?

Tags: logging, web, analytics

So I want to filter the GET requests to static resources (stylesheets, scripts, images ...) from a web access logs. I will feed the filtered logs to a Spark application to do log analytics. What would be the best way to filter the requests to the static files ?

Comment: Please, give us a few examples of your regular and static URLs.

Comment: Regular : GET /pages/politics/index.html?action=click&pgtype=Homepage
,Static : GET /css/0.1/print/styles.css , on the NY times website.

Comment: I would recommend you to move your static content to another domain (static.example.com) so you can filter your logs by the domain. Also, it's a great practice by itself.